# Categorize Data in a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-analysis

I have a column of numbers in my dataframe, i want to categorize these numbers into e.g high , low, excluded. How do i accomplish that. I am clueless , i have tried looking at the cut function and category datatype.

Comment: no i haven't..do i have to use numpy? thought pandas should be able to do that

Comment: sorry, I deleted the comment once I wrote an answer. Yes, you can use pandas.

Comment: IIUC `cut` should do the job. You can pass an array of `bins` (bins edges) to it and also `labels` of the bins. See an example in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html?highlight=cut#object-creation)

Comment: i have actually looked at the `cut` function before, it was confusing , couldn't grasp it

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A short example with `pd.cut`.

Let's start with some data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 8, 2, 5, 9, 15, 1]})
```

and, say, we want to assign the numbers to the following categories: `'low'` if a number is in the interval `[0, 2]`, `'mid'` for `(2, 8]`, `'high'` for `(8, 10]`, and we exclude numbers above 10 (or below 0).

Thus, we have 3 bins with edges: 0, 2, 8, 10. Now, we can use `cut` as follows:

```
pd.cut(df['A'], bins=[0, 2, 8, 10], include_lowest=True)
Out[33]: 
0     [0, 2]
1     (2, 8]
2     [0, 2]
3     (2, 8]
4    (8, 10]
5        NaN
6     [0, 2]
Name: A, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [[0, 2] < (2, 8] < (8, 10]]
```

The argument `include_lowest=True` includes the left end of the first interval. (If you want intervals open on the right, then use `right=False`.)

The intervals are probably not the best names for the categories. So, let's use names: `low/mid/high`:

```
pd.cut(df['A'], bins=[0, 2, 8, 10], include_lowest=True, labels=['low', 'mid', 'high'])
Out[34]: 
0     low
1     mid
2     low
3     mid
4    high
5     NaN
6     low
Name: A, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [low < mid < high]
```

The excluded number 15 gets a "category" `NaN`. If you prefer a more meaningful name, probably the simplest solution (there're other ways to deal with NaN's) is to add another bin and a category name, for example:

```
pd.cut(df['A'], bins=[0, 2, 8, 10, 1000], include_lowest=True, labels=['low', 'mid', 'high', 'excluded'])
Out[35]: 
0         low
1         mid
2         low
3         mid
4        high
5    excluded
6         low
Name: A, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [low < mid < high < excluded]
```

Comment: i get this example now, very helpful..bless

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty broad, but a good place to start might be this page in the documentation:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Or you could look into numpy.where

```
    import numpy as np
    df['is_high'] = np.where(df.['column_of_interest'] > 5 ,1,0)
```

Comment: Okay, i'd check that. Though i thought pandas should be able to do it without numpy

Comment: i have checked it out and my output is given in boolean, then i do this `high = result['Traded Value'] >  2.983150e+09` then `print result[high]` it gives me my desired ouput(displays numbers greater than that). I then tried to append the results to new column on my dataframe with `result = result.assign(high=high.values)` , when i display the dataframe, that new column turns out to be boolean instead of numeric values....i am confused on what to do.

Comment: you're desired output (in this comment) is not the same as the one in your question? Your problem appears to stem from the fact that 'high' is a bool mask. To return values you need to apply the mask to the columns you want to return values from.

Comment: eg) using the data in the documentation that I linked you can use: df['A_column_high_values'] = df.A[df['A']>10] ~ giving you a columns with the value of 'A' if it is higher than 10 and NaN otherwise.

Comment: yes it is different, but when i asked the question i never knew my output would be boolean, actually needed numeric values when i added the new column

Comment: so I think the 2nd of the comments will do what you need.

Comment: yeah should do...bless